# Out of Memory Vs Circuit Break Exception in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have ES with below configurations

- No. of Nodes = 1
- No. of Index = 1 with 5 shards and 0 replica
- Index contains 50 Million docs
- Index contains 5 fields
- Memory Max heap 2GB.
- Es Version 6.5.4

When I try to term aggregate field **Subject**(High cardinality field) as follows. Subject belongs to **keyword** type having length up-to 10 to 20 characters. I mentioned size equal to number of docs in the index to get all the results. Otherwise it only returns top 10.

```
{
    "aggs":
    {
        "subject":
        {
            "terms":
            {
                "field":"SUBJECT",
                "size" : 500000000

            }
        }
    }
}
```

It throws Out of memory. My question is

> Field data circuit breaker computes the field data size and stops the query.But why does circuit breaker not break the query and leads to **OOM**? Please help me out from this.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.PageCacheRecycler$2.newInstance(PageCacheRecycler.java:111) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.PageCacheRecycler$2.newInstance(PageCacheRecycler.java:108) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.recycler.DequeRecycler.obtain(DequeRecycler.java:53) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.recycler.AbstractRecycler.obtain(AbstractRecycler.java:33) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.recycler.DequeRecycler.obtain(DequeRecycler.java:28) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.recycler.FilterRecycler.obtain(FilterRecycler.java:39) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.recycler.Recyclers$3.obtain(Recyclers.java:119) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.recycler.FilterRecycler.obtain(FilterRecycler.java:39) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.PageCacheRecycler.intPage(PageCacheRecycler.java:155) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.AbstractBigArray.newIntPage(AbstractBigArray.java:126) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.BigIntArray.<init>(BigIntArray.java:45) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.BigArrays.newIntArray(BigArrays.java:558) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.BigArrays.resize(BigArrays.java:581) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.BigArrays.grow(BigArrays.java:596) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.BucketsAggregator.grow(BucketsAggregator.java:68) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.terms.GlobalOrdinalsStringTermsAggregator.getLeafCollector(GlobalOrdinalsStringTermsAggregator.java:133) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregatorBase.getLeafCollector(AggregatorBase.java:167) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregatorBase.getLeafCollector(AggregatorBase.java:40) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.apache.lucene.search.MultiCollector.getLeafCollector(MultiCollector.java:121) ~[lucene-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:01:13]
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FilterCollector.getLeafCollector(FilterCollector.java:40) ~[lucene-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:01:13]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.query.CancellableCollector.getLeafCollector(CancellableCollector.java:51) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:661) ~[lucene-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:01:13]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:191) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:471) ~[lucene-core-7.5.0.jar:7.5.0 b5bf70b7e32d7ddd9742cc821d471c5fabd4e3df - jimczi - 2018-09-18 13:01:13]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:269) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:107) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.loadOrExecuteQueryPhase(SearchService.java:330) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:377) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.access$100(SearchService.java:121) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$2.onResponse(SearchService.java:339) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$2.onResponse(SearchService.java:335) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
        at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$4.doRun(SearchService.java:1082) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
```

Comment: What is the data type of the SUBJECT field?

Comment: I have added the type in question. FYI it belongs to the keyword type @val

Answer (score 0):

Looks like aggregator is running OOM . if your query returns *only* few documents - you might get lucky with using "map" [execution hint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-execution-hint)

Comment: I have tried with "map". but no luck. OOM happens again

Comment: Unfortunately , it looks like you need to add more heap .

Comment: I actually added size parameter in the query. I forget to update in the question. Now I have updated the query

Comment: Since it is a high cardinality field , if map hint doesnt work -  AFAIK - you'll need to add more heap.